# haskell global variable for project config

Tags: haskell

I have a project and I read the config from a file. I want these configurations to be available every where.

What is the best way to do this in Haskell?

Someone said I could write to `System.Environment`. Is this OK?

Comment: Will the configurations be set once, or will they be dynamic?

Comment: @Carcigenicate they will be set once.

Comment: it would be nice if you explain the situation that they will be dynamic. it can come in handy.

Comment: IIRC (it's been awhile since I've written Haskell), Haskell has a delay mechanism, and atoms. Delays are used when you want to delay the initialization of something, but only set it once. Atoms are used when you need to update something more than once (I could be confusing terminology with a Clojure too. Pretty sure Haskell has equivalents though). Make sure it isn't fine to just set the configurations file in the main procedure, then thread it into any functions that need it, or use a state monad. I'd prefer those options to a global any day.

Answer (score 1):

For a complex configuration I would recommend to have a look at the reader Monad. An example can be found here: [Three Useful Monads](http://adit.io/posts/2013-06-10-three-useful-monads.html#the-reader-monad)